# Internet Explorer 11 replaces Authorization header || Not even working after using document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache', 'false');

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, ajax, jwt, internet-explorer-11

What would cause Internet Explorer to replace the HTTP header

```
Authorization : Bearer <server-provided-token>
```

with

```
Authorization : Negotiate <some token>
```

when making an AJAX request?

In Internet Explorer, some AJAX requests that are configured to contain the header `Authorization: Bearer ...` are being sent by Internet Explorer with the header `Authorization: Negotiate ...` instead.

For example, Fiddler shows that the first two of three requests contain the `Authorization : Bearer...` header, while the third suddenly contains the `Authorization : Negotiate...` header. The first two requests are successful, and the third fails because the request can't be properly authenticated.

All of the requests are constructed using the same client-side code, and are made one after another (within the span of a second). I have verified that the Authorization header correctly contains the Bearer token in all three cases up until the point the request is provided to the browser.

Also, I'm not seeing the same behavior in Chrome; it's only occurring in IE.

Request 1

```
GET http://localhost/myapp/api/User HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: Bearer oEXS5IBu9huepzW6jfh-POMA18AUA8yWZsPfBPZuFf_JJxq-DKIt0JDyPXSiGpmV_cpT8FlL3D1DN-Tv5ZbT73MTuBOd5y75-bsx9fZvOeJgg04JcO0cUajdCH2h5QlMP8TNwgTpHg-TR9FxyPk3Kw6bQ6tQCOkOwIG_FmEJpP89yrOsoYJoCfrAoZ7M4PVcik9F9qtPgXmWwXB2eHDtkls44wITF_yM_rPm5C47OPCvMVTPz30KwoEPi6fHUcL3qHauP-v9uypv2e48TyPHUwLYmNFxyafMhBx4TkovnRcsdLHZiHmSjMq0V9a2Vw70
Referer: http://localhost/client/login.html
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: localhost
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Request 2

```
POST http://localhost/myapp/api/Permissions HTTP/1.1
Referer: http://localhost/client/#/Dashboard
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer oEXS5IBu9huepzW6jfh-POMA18AUA8yWZsPfBPZuFf_JJxq-DKIt0JDyPXSiGpmV_cpT8FlL3D1DN-Tv5ZbT73MTuBOd5y75-bsx9fZvOeJgg04JcO0cUajdCH2h5QlMP8TNwgTpHg-TR9FxyPk3Kw6bQ6tQCOkOwIG_FmEJpP89yrOsoYJoCfrAoZ7M4PVcik9F9qtPgXmWwXB2eHDtkls44wITF_yM_rPm5C47OPCvMVTPz30KwoEPi6fHUcL3qHauP-v9uypv2e48TyPHUwLYmNFxyafMhBx4TkovnRcsdLHZiHmSjMq0V9a2Vw70
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 1419
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

<Post Data Removed>
```

Request 3

```
GET http://localhost/myapp/api/UserPreferences/Dashboard HTTP/1.1
Referer: http://localhost/client/#/Dashboard
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Negotiate YHsGBisGAQUFAqBxMG+gMDAuBgorBgEEAYI3AgIKBgkqhkiC9xIBAgIGCSqGSIb3EgECAgYKKwYBBAGCNwICHqI7BDlOVExNU1NQAAEAAACXsgjiBgAGADMAAAALAAsAKAAAAAYBsR0AAAAPVk1ERVZFTlYtU1JTQ0VSSVM=
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Connection: Keep-Alive
DNT: 1
Host: localhost
```

The requests are being made via the AngularJS `$http` service, and the back-end is ASP.NET Web API hosted in IIS.

I have tried fixing this issue with

```
document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache', 'false');"
```

But this leads to another issue. That is if I log in using form based authentication in my application then on page refresh the IIS picks up the windows authenticated user and changes the current logged in user to window's authenticated user.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  We're having the same problem with IE11.  When we  have the site set to use Basic auth, IE overwrites our authorization: bearer header with its own authorization: basic header.  The same site set to windows auth always works fine, and basic auth works with chrome.  We can't get IE11 AND basic auth to cooperate as it overwrites the header, out of our control.... frustrating